# The remote byteman agent reported an error

Tags: byteman

I need a little help to understand what's wrong with by two rules.

```
RULE inefficient FilterOutputStream write trace
CLASS java.io.FilterOutputStream
METHOD write( int )
AT RETURN
IF TRUE
DO traceStack("*** Slow write calls ***", 10)
ENDRULE


RULE inefficient FilterInputStream read trace
CLASS java.io.FilterInputStream
METHOD read( )
AT RETURN
IF TRUE
DO traceStack("*** Slow read calls ***", 10)
ENDRULE
```

Running bmcheck shows

```
Checking rule inefficient FilterOutputStream write trace against class java.io.FilterOutputStream
Parsed rule "inefficient FilterOutputStream write trace" for class java.io.FilterOutputStream
Type checked rule "inefficient FilterOutputStream write trace"

Checking rule inefficient FilterInputStream read trace against class java.io.FilterInputStream
Parsed rule "inefficient FilterInputStream read trace" for class java.io.FilterInputStream
Type checked rule "inefficient FilterInputStream read trace"

TestScript: no errors
```

When submitting the rules I am seeing this error

```
$ jboss/byteman/byteman-download-4.0.17/bin/bmsubmit.sh -u /somewhere/scripts/InefficientIOStreamHandling.btm
Failed to process request: java.lang.Exception: The remote byteman agent reported an error:
ERROR failed to find loaded rule with name inefficient FilterOutputStream write trace
ERROR failed to find loaded rule with name inefficient FilterInputStream read trace
ERROR No rule scripts to remove

-- Args were: [/somewhere/scripts/InefficientIOStreamHandling.btm]
java.lang.Exception: The remote byteman agent reported an error:
ERROR failed to find loaded rule with name inefficient FilterOutputStream write trace
ERROR failed to find loaded rule with name inefficient FilterInputStream read trace
ERROR No rule scripts to remove

    at org.jboss.byteman.agent.submit.Submit$Comm.readResponse(Submit.java:966)
    at org.jboss.byteman.agent.submit.Submit.submitRequest(Submit.java:790)
    at org.jboss.byteman.agent.submit.Submit.deleteScripts(Submit.java:697)
    at org.jboss.byteman.agent.submit.Submit.deleteRulesFromFiles(Submit.java:649)
    at org.jboss.byteman.agent.submit.Submit.main(Submit.java:1144)
$
```

There is this in the console of the jvm

```
$ TransformListener() : handling connection on port 9091

$
```

Is there something else I should be checking ?

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
$
```

Answer (score 0):

should be using bmsubmit.sh -l to **load** a script.